# Node.js GraphicsMagick - Compose 2 images together with position and dimensions

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, graphicsmagick, gm

I'm trying to compose two images on top of each other using the Node.js [gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) library. For the final image, `avatar.png` needs to go on top of `bg.png`. Here's the code I started with:

```
const image = gm("bg.png")
    .composite("avatar.png");
```

This works the way it should, but I also needed to move the image over to an `x`, `y` of `50`, `50`, so I used the `geometry()` function:

```
const image = gm("bg.png")
    .composite("avatar.png")
    .geometry("+50+50");
```

The next problem is that I needed to scale the image up to be `200`x`200`, so I tried a few things to do this:

```
const image = gm("bg.png")
    .composite("avatar.png")
    .geometry("200x200+50+50");
```

This ended up scaling `bg.png` to be as close to `200`x`200` as possible while still preserving the aspect ratio of the image. Since that didn't work, I tried this:

```
const image = gm("bg.png")
    .composite("avatar.png")
    .resize("200x200")
    .geometry("+50+50");
```

This just ignored the `resize()` function and didn't scale anything at all. Swapping the order of `resize()` and `geometry()` also didn't do anything.

How can I scale `avatar.png` to be `200`x`200`?

Comment: Try .geometry("200x200+50+50!")

Comment: @JoshH That squashes `bg.png` to be `200`x`200`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like any function that gets called only applies to the image passed in the constructor even after calling composite.

You have do the processing separately:

```
gm("bg.png")
  .geometry("+50+50")
  .toBuffer('PNG', function(err, buffer) {
    if (err) return handle(err);
    console.log('done!');
    gm(buffer, 'image.png')
      .composite('avatar.png')
      .geometry("200x200+50+50!")
      .write('output.png', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

Good luck!

Comment: This turns `bg.png` into a `200`x`200` image and doesn't modify `avatar.png` at all

Answer (score 0):

Like Josh H said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58844856/8961491), it looks like I need to resize `avatar.png` separately, and then compose it with `bg.png`. Here's my final code:

```
gm("avatar.png")
    .resize(200, 200)
    .write("resizedAvatar.png", () => {
        gm("bg.png")
            .composite("resizedAvatar.png")
            .geometry("+50+50")
            .toBuffer("PNG", (err, buffer) => {
                // do whatever with `buffer`
            });

    });
```